# what occurs in memory when using &$variable in PHP?

Tags: php

when using & beside variables what happens in memory?

```
&$variable_name;
```

I think so clear and dont have more details to add to the question!

Comment: You pass a pointer (reference) to the variable and not the actual bytes contained in that variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)